# Trying to get a stream link of a video file from GDRIVE API

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-drive-api

I'm trying to get a stream link for my video files to stream it on my web app from google drive api, but its not working properly. I have double checked the docs for any errors in syntax and i can't seem to find any.
for context here is my code:

`

```
  drive.files.get({fileId: myfileId,alt: 'media'},{responseType: 'stream'},  (err, res) => {
    if (err) return console.log(`The API returned an error: ${err}`);
    console.log(res)
  });
```

`

I'm getting a passthrough object in res.data field and its giving an error of "Unknown output format: 'media' ". The file i'm trying to stream is a .mp4 file.

I have also double checked my authentication and its working fine because i was able to retrieve my folder id and file id using the api.

Am i doing anything wrong here? Any help would be appreciated.
THANKS.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have authenticated the client library, you can use the following code to get a stream link for a video file stored in Google Drive

// Replace `fileId` with the ID of the video file you want to stream
const fileId = '1234567890';

// Get the file from Google Drive
const file = await drive.files.get({ fileId, alt: 'media' });

// Get the stream link for the file
const streamLink = file.data;

Comment: did that but got a passthrough object in data field not a stream link.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).